# multilanguage script adapting to database connection

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm using one script of very good multilanguage in my site.

http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html

But unfortanly I have a problem:

I need to manipulate the information that is inside of the languages pages (`languages/lang.en.php`), to edit from my backoffice instead of going to the languages page and fill from there.

It is possible to make echos from the filing-cabinets `languages/lang.en.php` for example?

I tried but no sucess, I liked to communicate the languages pages to my database.

I tried to see if i can echo this part of the code in the language file:

$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'My website page title';

Change to

$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = '';
But doesnt work, it looks like that just works whit html tags.

Comment: What have you tried so far (demonstrate by posting *your* code), and into which concrete problem did you run when changing from file database to mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

if in your php page you have the title set as:

```
<title><?php echo $lang['PAGE_TITLE']; ?></title>
//change this to
<title><?php echo $lang-pagetitle; ?></title>
//and at the top of the document
$lang-pagetitle = $lang['PAGE_TITLE'];
//and when it needs to be changed, put this above where the title is echoed, 
//after where $lang-pagetitle is initially defined:

if(whatever condition) {
$lang-pagetitle = "something else";
}
```